# Append to byte array using swig

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, swig

I would like to append to a Java byte[] from C++ using swig. The trick is to do this without calling GetByteArrayElements as this would make a copy of the byte[] if the byte[] cannot be pinned.

Without swig, we can easily do this with SetByteArrayRegion - write number of bytes to the byte[] directly.
The problem with swig is that:

- the code that does the actual work is in .cpp - for example read the contents of a file and put it in a string fileContents. The c++ code doesn’t have access to the jni fields.
- The code that does SetByteArrayRegion is in the .i file - it does not have access to fileContents data produced by the c++ function.

I could not find any example to append data generated by c++ function into a byte[] using swig, without pinning the whole buffer and just using SetByteArrayRegion to copy the necessary data over.

Sample c++ functionality to achieve:

```
    void append(char *s, int pos) {
      char* fileContents = readFromFile();
      strcat(s+pos, fileContents);
    }
```

Possible work-around solution:

In the .i file we do the actual implementation (call readFromFile) and with those results call SetByteArrayRegion directly in the %template . This is rather hacky.

Answer (score 0):

java arrays cannot grow. Once made, their size is locked in. The only option is to make a new byte array and return that (and write whatever code ends up calling your code doesn't merely pass a byte array, but will also replace its own variable with whatever you return; if it does not do that there is nothing you can do).